# Forecast function in obiee, how to use?

Tags: oracle, analytics, forecasting, obiee

I was trying to use forecast function in Obiee 12c. I used it in one analysis it worked, but when I used it in another with other measure it displays straight line, however the measure itself is fluctuating.

I couldn't get why the same function that worked in one case won't work in similar one.

Here is how I used it:

```
FORECAST("KPI Результаты Сотрудника"."Indicator", ("Time"."YEAR","Time"."QUARTER","Time"."MONTH"), 'high', 'modelType=arima;numPeriods=%1;predictionInterval=%2', 6, 90)
```

Below is the resulting graph

[image]

Did someone tried it? How can we get more realistic forecast?

Edit 1. Here is my data in tabular format. Here I selected one employee and its KPI for last 6 months, I want to forecast for the next 6 months

```
Year    Quarter    Month   Indicator    High    Low    Forecast
2016    1             01    70           
                      02    47           
                      03    45           
        2             04    73           
                      05    47           
                      06    43           
        3             07                  74    34      54
                      08                  74    34      54
                      09                  74    34      54
        4             10                  74    34      54
                      11                  74    34      54
                      12                  74    34      54
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes i have worked on oracle obiee and i know what is the issue,
looks like your data does not contain seasonality and trend components, if these component are absent then forecast will be simple average of previous value and you will get straight line, it will be helpful if you upload your input dataset.

Comment: I edited my answer to include data in table view. What do you mean by trend componenets? Should I add something to my dataset? The table itself is joined with time Dimension in order to correspond to Calendar. Can you help me to find what is wrong here?

Comment: Bro to do good forecast we need more historical data so that the forecast model can easily find the seasonality and trends present in data. Your historical data is only 6 month which is very less so it will be very difficult for forecast model to find seasonality and trend present in data and you are forecasting  next 6 month which is very difficult for model, there fore the model is simply giving you average of last 6 month data as forecast.

Comment: Suggestion : you should have atleast 2+ years of historical data for good forecast.

Comment: I get it now why the other one worked, it had more that 2+ years of data. Thanks for full explanation @Zeeshan

Comment: @Sherzodbek- my pleasure ;)